# Design Decision: Object with a lot of empty fields

Tags: apex, custom-object

I want to design a table that will contain a lot of fields. I can normalize that table into a set of tables. But in that case, individual rows from those tables will count under storage (each row size is 2kb irrespective of the number of fields). Or, I can have a single table with a large number of fields. In that case, Let's say for half of the data stored, those fields will be empty.

We know, in Salesforce each row size is 2kb irrespective of the number of fields. So, why not add all the fields on the same table instead of having separate tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that. It would save money in the short term. But for the admins and developers it would make life much, much harder. Every minute that I think longer about the consequences, I foresee more and more challenges.

Every validation rule, every SOQL query would first have to filter on the appropriate kind of record. Development will take longer, more errors will be made. Simple administrative tasks will suddenly become huge challenges.

And the more you develop and configure your org, the more complicated life will get. Just to save some money in the short term. Don't go there.

Comment: Thanks @Sander for answering the question. Do you know, any impact on underlying custom code in terms of performance like query performance, dml performance, db cpu time etc.?

Comment: @RajendraSinghNagar From your question it looks like you are still considering to do this. Please reread my answer, especially the last sentence :-)